# Correct pattern for underscore jst tempates when compiled by grunt-contrib-jst -undefined error

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have managed to narrow down the error message I am receiving to one line.

```
ReferenceError: property is not defined

((__t = ( property )) == null ? '' : __t) +
```

The View Controller is as follows (simplified for brevity)

```
workSpace.viewMain = Backbone.View.extend({
// WORKS
// template: _.template($("#desk-view-main").html()), 
// DOESNT WORK
template: _.template(window.JST["public/js/app/templates/desk-view-main.html"]()), 
// DOESNT WORK
// template: _.template(window.JST["public/js/app/templates/desk-view-main.html"](), {"key": "value"}), 
el: '#pw-main',

initialize: function() {
  this.render();
},

render: function(a) {
  var dictionary = {"key": "value"}
  var html = that.template(dictionary);
  $(that.el).append(html);
}

});
```

The compiled file looks as follows

```
this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};

this["JST"]["public/js/app/templates/desk-view-main.html"] = function(obj) {
obj || (obj = {});
var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape;
with (obj) {
__p += '  <nav id="tweak"></nav>\n  <div class="desk">\n    <h3>Workspace:</h3>\n    <strong> ' +
((__t = ( property )) == null ? '' : __t) +
'</strong>\n\n    <h3>end Workspace:</h3>\n  </div>\n</div>\n';

}
return __p
};
```

From the following public/js/app/templates/desk-view-main.html

```
<div class="desk">
  <h3>Workspace:</h3>
  <span> <%= property %></span>
  <h3>end Workspace:</h3>
</div>
```

So far I haven't been able to work out the correct pattern to use a compiled template with variables (it works fine if I remove the property variable).

Comment: It's a javascript object. You're correct however, it has an obvious typo.  var dictionary = {"key":"value"}

Comment: So you're calling a template that uses `property` with an object like `{"key": "value"}` rather than `{property: 'some value'}`?

Comment: As I understood it, the quotation marks around the property  are equally valid. so window.obj = {key: "some value" } and window.obj = {"property":"some value"} are both valid javascript (although the former is probably clearer and more correct.  Having tested it ,seems that both ways work when passing to the inline template, it seems to be a problem with setting the JST['path/templ.js'] and the way this is parsed by underscores _.template method.

Comment: Yeah but `key` and `property` are different keys...